# Issue in triggering event on bootstrap switch?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-switch

there is one element in my html called bootstrap switch and I wantto trigger onchange event on that switch. I tried different events but none of them worked for me. then i saw event listened on particular switch so I found already onchange event is there triggering from jquery.min.js. but I want to fire my own event to do some stuff. How do I proceed and cancel default event ?

**html bootstrap switch**

```
<div class="col-md-3">
   <div class="actions">
     <input type="checkbox" name="dummydata" id="dummydata" class="make-switch" checked data-on="success" data-on-color="success" data-off-color="warning" data-size="small"> 

    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: look into `e.preventDefault();` to prevent default action

Comment: where should I write this code @Toxide82

Comment: can you get a unminified version of jquery then add this to the event which its firing then minify it again.